# AngularJS tab navigation and module injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I have two modules in two separate files as so:

first.js

```
var app = angular.module('first',['ngGrid']);  
app.controller('firstTest',function($scope))
{  
   ...
});
```

second.js

```
var app = angular.module('second',['ngGrid']);  
app.controller('secondTest',function($scope))
{  
   ...
});
```

I now want to use these two modules again in a navigation type view as so:

tabs.js

```
var app = angular.module('myTabs',['first','second']);  
$scope.tabs = [    
    {title: "first", content:first.firstTest},
    {title: "second", content:second.secondTest},
];  

$scope.navType='pills';  
});
```

What happens is that I get the following error:

```
unknown provider firstProvider <- first
```

So the questions I have are
1) Is this the correct way to go about doing tabbed navigation
2) What is the proper technique to handle the injection of the `first` and `second` modules?

Answer (score 0):

In our application we have used `ngClass` directive.

```
ng-class="{active:isActive('/tab1')}"
```

Where `isActive` is the function defined in a scope. This function requires `$location` variable.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
$scope.isActive = function(route) {
    return route === $location.path();
}
});
```

You can directly jump to a specific tab using URL location if you use this kind of solution.

Also look at `$routeProvider` for reference.